# Minimum time for GPS updates on Android

Tags: android, gps

I have an application where I need refresh rates on the GPS location in the range of every 0.1 seconds.  Battery usage is not an issue for me.  The velocities will be in the 50-60 m/s range so it is feasible for me to sample every 0.1 seconds.  I set the location manager as

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,010,(float)0.01,this);
```

That should update every 0.01 seconds but it seems that the minimum it will update is once every second.  Is there any way to get 0.1 sec?

Comment: Why do you need an update every tenth of a second, especially considering its accuracy may be off by a good portion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to get location update multiple time in less than a second. What are u trying to achieve by getting location update every 0.1 sec ?